# How to remove falsy values when splitting a string with a non-whitespace separator

Tags: python, string, split

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

> **`str.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)`**
>
> If *sep* is given, consecutive delimiters are not grouped together and
>   are deemed to delimit empty strings (for example, `'1,,2'.split(',')`
>   returns `['1', '', '2']`). The *sep* argument may consist of multiple
>   characters (for example, `'1<>2<>3'.split('<>')` returns `['1', '2', '3']`).
>   Splitting an empty string with a specified separator returns
>   `['']`.
>
> If *sep* is not specified or is `None`, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently, splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace with a `None` separator returns `[]`.

So to use the keyword argument `sep=`, **is the following the pythonic way to remove the falsy items?**

```
[w for w in s.strip().split(' ') if w]
```

If it's just whitespaces (`\s\t\n`), `str.split()` will suffice but let's say we are trying to split on another character/substring, the if-condition in the list comprehension is necessary. Is that right?

Comment: None is not a space character. I don't even know what Noney means, but the method works as documented. You have no None elements in a string

Comment: Why not just use `split()`? Moreover, what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Side-note: If you're using no-arg `split`, calling `strip` first is redundant; the `split` will already remove the leading and trailing whitespace, without adding an extra method call and temporary `str`.

Comment: See updated question.

Comment: It'll be great if anyone could explain or point to the CPython code that does `str.split()` and the difference between `sep=None` and `sep=` something else.

Comment: What is a "noney" item?

Comment: @alvas: Why do you need the source code reference? The docs are super clear here: `sep=None` is special, nothing else is. Implementation-wise, it's all [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.6/Objects/stringlib/split.h#l54), there is a special case for `None` (`split_whitespace`), an optimized (but behaviorally the same as the next case) case for splitting on a single character (`split_char`), and a general case for everything else (`split`).

Comment: @ShadowRanger, thanks for the link to code!! That's very helpful. It's just my curiosity and preference to know where the code comes from beyond the doc ;P Thanks for the explanation too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be obtuse, you could use `filter(None, x)` to remove falsey items:

```
>>> list(filter(None, '1,2,,3,'.split(',')))
['1', '2', '3']
```

Probably less Pythonic. It might be clearer to iterate over the items specifically:

```
for w in '1,2,,3,'.split(','):
    if w:
        …
```

This makes it clear that you're skipping the empty items and not relying on the fact that str.split sometimes skips empty items.

I'd just as soon use a regex, either to skip consecutive runs of the separator (but watch out for the end):

```
>>> re.split(r',+', '1,2,,3,')
['1', '2', '3', '']
```

or to find everything that's not a separator:

```
>>> re.findall(r'[^,]+', '1,2,,3,')
['1', '2', '3']
```

If you want to go *way* back in Python's history, there were two separate functions, `split` and `splitfields`. I think the name explains the purpose. The first splits on any whitespace, useful for arbitrary text input, and the second behaves predictably on some delimited input. They were implemented in pure Python before v1.6.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you might just need a hand in understanding the documentation.  In your example, you pretty much are demonstrating the differences in the algorithm mentioned in documentation. Not using the `sep` keyword argument more or less is like using `sep=' '` and then throwing out the empty strings. When you have multiple spaces in a row the algorithm splits those and finds `None`. Because you were explicit that you wanted everything split by a space it converts None to an empty string. Changing `None` to an empty string is good practice in this case, because it avoids changing the signature of the function (or in other words what the functions returns), in this case it returns a list of strings.

Below is showing how an empty string with 4 spaces is treated differently...

```
>>> empty = '   '
>>> s = 'this is   an   irritating string with  random spacing  .'
>>> empty.split()
[]
>>> empty.split(' ')
['', '', '', '']
```

For you question, just use `split()` with no `sep` argument

Answer (score -1):

well your string
s = 'this is   an   irritating string with  random spacing  .',
which is containing more than one white spaces that's why **empty.split(' ')**  is  returning noney value.

you would have to remove extra white space from string s and can get desired result.